# Add audio post from smartphone

Tags: mobile, audio

I'm working on a personal website for a friend of mine. It's a travel diary and I want to let him add as many post types as possible. I've been able to easily let him add photos and post (of course) and automatic video from youtube account. But I can't find an easy way to let him record audio post from his smartphone. He has Android (a platform I don't know very well) but on my iPhone there's not an easy way to do it. Theoretically I should be able to automatically retrieve podcast from a soundcloud account, but I can't find a way to post on soundcloud from smartphone.
Of course iPhone doesn't let you simply upload an MP3, I don't know if the android version let's you do that. Even if upload a file it's not very elegant, I preferred to use something easier. For instance use mobile version of youtube to record a video and upload it it's very easy. A plugin simply retrieve the latest video from his youtube account. Any suggestion for audio?

Comment: Please note that asking for plugin recommendations is not in scope. If you are interested in off-the-shelf solution for this, this site just isn't a good place to ask.

Comment: Well, actually I believe this should be a mix of two. I guess I do need an app to natively record audio on the smartphone, and a custom code to somehow retrieve the audio file and create a post with it.